# Not able to print this 2D array (weird output) in C

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to read a text file with 100 numbers like `1 2 45 55 100` [text file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CiYYcHaOxUv4MPsbeZQqYcUR6CzunRJk/view?usp=sharing) (all on a single line) and then put them in a 10x10 array (2D array).

```
736.2 731.6 829.8 875.8 568.3 292.2 231.1 868.9 66.7 811.9 292.0 967.6 419.3 578.1 322.5 471.7 980.0 378.8 784.1 116.8 900.4 355.3 645.7 603.6 409.1 652.1 144.1 590.6 953.1 954.0 502.0 689.3 685.6 331.9 565.1 253.9 624.1 796.2 122.8 690.7 608.0 414.8 658.3 27.3 992.9 980.8 499.0 972.8 359.7 283.1 89.7 260.1 638.4 735.4 863.6 47.5 387.5 7.7 638.1 340.6 961.7 140.1 29.8 647.3 471.9 594.9 901.2 96.0 391.1 24.0 786.7 999.1 438.7 445.0 26.4 431.6 425.9 525.4 404.4 785.6 808.5 494.1 45.7 447.0 229.5 909.3 494.4 617.0 917.0 132.5 957.5 878.8 272.6 987.4 526.1 744.5 582.3 427.3 840.5 973.3
```

[image: Weird Output of array]

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NR 10
#define NC 10

int main(void) {
    int numbers[9][9];
    int i = 0;
    int count;
    int j = 0;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    for (count = 1; count < 101; count++) {   
        fscanf(file, "%d", &numbers[i][j]);
        j++;
        if ((count != 1) && (count % 10 == 0)) {
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
      
    fclose(file);
    
    int p = 0;
    int q = 0;
    for (p = 0; p < NR; p++) {
        for (q = 0; q < NC; q++) {
            printf("%d", numbers[p][q]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Weird how? `int numbers[10][10];` needed. Give some space between numbers printf("%d\t", numbers[p][q]);`

Comment: Just use `i` & `j`, drop `count` variable, it make logic tedious.

Comment: Spaces make the numbers look less jumbled yet still it does not read/print the actual numbers from the text rather a bunch of random numbers

Comment: You need to share the `numbers.txt` file contents in question.

Comment: Just edited and shared it on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- the matrix is too small, make it `numbers[NR][NC]`.
- you do not check for `fopen` failure: you will have undefined behavior if the file **numbers.txt** is not in the current directory or cannot be open for reading.
- you read the file contents as integers, but the file contains floating point numbers with a `.` decimal separator: the second and subsequent `fscanf()` will get stuck on the `.` and keep returning `0` without modifying the destination number, leaving the matrix mostly uninitialized. Make the matrix `double numbers[NR][NC]`, read the numbers with `%lf` and test for conversion failure.
- the counting method in the reading loop is weird. Just use 2 nested for loops with proper counter and tests.
- printing the matrix contents, you should output at least a space between numbers so the output is readable.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NR 10
#define NC 10

int main() {
    double numbers[NR][NC];
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open numbers.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NR; i++) {   
        for (int j = 0; j < NC; j++) {   
            if (fscanf(file, "%lf", &numbers[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error reading number at row %d, col %d\n",
                        i + 1, j + 1);
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    
    for (int p = 0; p < NR; p++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < NC; q++) {
            printf(" %5g", numbers[p][q]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Turns out changing scanf's data to %lf solved it. I was trying %f and %d before, silly me

Answer (score 1):

As [SparKot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/835145/sparkot) noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817063/not-able-to-print-this-2d-aray-weird-output-in-c/71817558#comment126910831_71817063), to read a 10x10 matrix, you need to define the matrix with 10x10 elements:

```
int numbers[10][10];
```

That has to be one of the weirder ways of reading a 10x10 matrix that I've ever seen.  Why not go for a simple approach of nested loops.  Since the data contains floating-point numbers, you need to read them as `double` (or perhaps `float`) values.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        double double_val;
        if (fscanf(file, "%lf", &double_val) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to read matrix[i][j]\n", i, j);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        numbers[i][j] = double_val;
    }
}
```

The mess with `double_val` works around the data containing floating point numbers and your original code trying to read integers.  You'll get one valid value; thereafter, `fscanf()` will return `0` because the `.` is not a part of a valid integer.  This highlights the importance of checking the return value from `fscanf()` and its relatives.

Frankly, you should be using `double numbers[10][10];` for the data from the file.  Then you could read directly into the array:

```
if (fscanf("%lf", &numbers[i][j]) != 1)
```

But you'd need to check (and probably change) all the rest of the code too.

Comment: Thank you. The reason for reading matrix like that is because I am a newbie so  to be safe that when it is reading txt file it goes exactly one step forward and only scans the next number when it goes to the next column, I used the count iteration

Answer (score -2):

Clear all a common condition that causes programs to crash; they are often associated with a file named core.
code is showing segmentation fault.

Comment: Probably because you don't have the file... That's not answering OP's question.